# Woocommerce. Как получить прямую ссылку покупки товара

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Я добавил товары в `woocommerce` и  оформил так как надо.

Как узнать прямую ссылку для покупки товара, чтобы не в корзину товар добавился, а сразу на страницу оплаты перешел клиент.

Мне нужен такой функционал: человек нажимает на клавишу КУПИТЬ и переходит на страничку, где нужно будет заполнить например 4 поля (имя, фамилия, адрес, телефон) и после нажимает ПОДТВЕРДИТЬ и переходит на пайпал оплату.

Корзина вообще не нужна, при каждом другом нажатии КУПИТЬ, должен быть всегда один товар на котором нажали клавишу КУПИТЬ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть плагин [WooCommerce Direct Checkout](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-direct-checkout/)

Мне кажется, это то, что Вам нужно

Answer (score 0):

> сразу на страницу оплаты перешел клиент

вашсайт/checkout/

При этом нужно оформлять "от клиента", а ему тоже авторизовываться.

Comment: Мне не нужна авторизация и регистрация вообще, и корзина товаров тоже мне не нужна! Мне нужен только такой функционал - человек нажимает на клавишу КУПИТЬ и преходит на страничку где нужно будет заполнить например 4 поля(имя,фамилия,адрес,телефон)и после нажимает ПОДТВЕРДИТЬ и переходит на пайпал оплату, вот примерно такое.Корзина вообще не нужна, при каждом другом нажатии КУПИТЬ - должен быть всегда один товар на котором нажали клавишу КУПИТЬ

Comment: Тогда.вопрос задан некорректно. Я его понял как "я добавил товар в корзину, оформил заказ, а потом клиенту надо дать эту ссылку для завершения заказа" . А вот KAGG Design, вероятно, понял правильно и показал плагин.

Comment: Кароче ты просто зашел на стековерфлоу, Прочел тему непонятно как, насоветовал тут непонятно чего, и еще правил мой вопрос что теперь вообще непонятно в нем что мне нужно? Да ты ценный пользователь этого сайта...

Comment: @rodgers не кипятитесь ) SeVlad не понял ваш вопрос отчасти потому, что вопрос был сформулирован немного сумбурно. Вы можете его уточнить.